# Wordpress pagination on custom post type being overwritten by amount in 'Reading'

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Under 'Reading' in admin, I have "Blog pages show at most" set to 9, which is correct for my posts. I have a CPT called 'career', and I'm displaying a different amount of posts per page 12. Here is my custom query

```
     <?php $custom_query = new WP_Query(array( 
        'post_type' => 'career',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => $paged,
        ));
    ?>
    <?php while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/career/default' ); ?>
    
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php kodr_page_nav(); ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But for some reason, it's still using the amount from "Reading" to apply the pagination. So rather than the pagination appearing when there are 12+ posts on this CPT, it's appearing after 9+ posts. Any ideas why?